# next and previous page function with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a function that allows my tabled data to display only a certain number of rows per page and have a next and previous page functionality without using an external library like vuetify. I managed to restrict my table to 15 rows per page but I'm not able to go to the next page. This is my next and previous functions

```
nextButton() {
     if (this.quotes.length > this.rowsPerPage * (this.currentPage + 1)) {
       this.currentPage += 1; 
     } else {
       this.currentPage += 0;
     }
   },
   previousButton() {
    if (this.currentPage > 0) {
      this.currentPage -= 1; 
    } else {
      this.currentPage -=0;
    }
   },
```

This is my computed function that limits to 15 per page

```
computed: {
    quotesPerPage() {
      return this.quotes.slice(0, this.rowsPerPage);
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slice the data using **start index** and **end index** as you can see here in [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

first calculate the `startIndex` which is the current page index (0 based) times the rows per page.

The `endIndex` will be the `startIndex` plus the `rowsPerPage`.

example:

```
index: 0, start: 0, end: 10
index: 1, start: 10, end: 20
index: 2, start: 20, end: 30
```

I created this code to show you how you can calculate the indices

I also rewrited the next and previous code to use `Math.max` and `Math.min` but is just to show you a different way to calculate the next and previous page, there is also a way to do this using `if-else` statements

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#pagination-app",
  computed: {
    data: function() {
       const startIndex = this.pageIndex * this.rowsPerPage;
       const endIndex = startIndex + this.rowsPerPage;
       return this.rows.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    },
    page: function() {
      return this.pageIndex + 1;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    next() {
      const maxPageIndex = Math.ceil(this.rows.length / this.rowsPerPage) - 1;
      this.pageIndex = Math.min(this.pageIndex + 1, maxPageIndex);
    },
    previous() {
      this.pageIndex = Math.max(this.pageIndex - 1, 0);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      rows: [
        { name: "this is the first" },
        { name: "second" },
        { name: "third" },
        { name: "this is the first of second page" },
        { name: "b from 2th" },
        { name: "c from 3th" },
        { name: "foo" },
        { name: "bar, the last item" }
      ],
      pageIndex: 0,
      rowsPerPage: 3
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block; /** because the code window is so small **/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="pagination-app" class="demo">
  <div>
    <div class="row" v-for="item in data">
      {{ item.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="previous()">previous</button>
  <button v-on:click="next()">next</button>
  <div>
    page: {{ page }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm for some reason it doesn't work. I still get all the data returned back on 1 page.

Comment: Are you using the rows to store all the data? the `data` itself is the data aviable to view and the `rows` is to store all the rows that comes from backend (sorry about the variable names)

Comment: yeah, you used `data` and `quotes` to store all the items, so in the html file you also need to replace `data` to `dataDisplay`

Comment: I updated the code a bit to fit my own needs to test it out, so the data is coming from quotes.

Comment: Ah I got it now

Comment: Good, so.. if this answer helped you don't forget to accept it  or if you solved alone post your solution as your own answer and accept it (is also valid)